# Specify og:image for particular pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add open graph meta data for og:image via custom field on Wordpress reference to this [link](https://www.webhostinghero.com/how-to-specify-the-facebook-ogimage-tag-in-wordpress/) but it does not work for me. Is this function correct? I am following all steps same.

PS: I dont use plugin for SEO

thanks

[image: Custom field]

```
function insert_og_image() {

if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'og_image', true) && is_single()) {
$output = '<meta property="og:image" content="'. get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'og_image', true) .'" />';
}

echo $output;
}
add_action('wp_head','insert_og_image');
```

Comment: have you supplied a custom field `og_image` with the url of the image?

Comment: yes @TheWolf I am, I just updated the picture in my question. thanks

Comment: you might be testing it on urls which are not `is_single()`? also can you put that `echo $output;` inside the if statement, its bothering me. also at least tab the statements inside your conditional statement.

Comment: Is this for a page? (as in, when you added the og_image field you were in the edit view of one of the items on the Pages section in wp-admin?) That's the first thing that comes to mind when I see this seeing as the `is_single()` function being used there returns false for pages. If thats the case you'll want to swap that for `is_singular()`